# pdfplumber extract_table settings

Tags: python, pdf

I am using pdfplumber to extract data from a table but there is some strange quark in the extract_table function that I would like to try and fix by adjusting the pdfplumber settings so that I don't have to resort to regex. The following table exists in a pdf document and when it is extracted by `Page.extract_table()` I get the following output:
[image]

```
[['METER\nNUMBER', 'METER\nTYPE', 'METER\n SIZE', 'SERVICE\nPERIOD', 'SERVICE\nDAYS', 'BEGIN\nREAD', 'END GALLONS BILLED\nREAD (PER 1,000)'], ['19XXXXXX', 'Water', '3/4"', '10/02/2021 — 10/26/2021', '25', '1.9', '5.3 3.4']]
```

Notice the last two columns do some sort of strange concatenation but none of the settings from https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#table-extraction-settings alter the output any better (nearly all of them make the problem worse or have no impact at all). Unfortunately, I cant post the original pdf here but hopefully, someone is familiar enough with pdfplumber that they have seen or resolved an issue similar to this.
The desired output is:

```
[['METER\nNUMBER', 'METER\nTYPE', 'METER\n SIZE', 'SERVICE\nPERIOD', 'SERVICE\nDAYS', 'BEGIN\nREAD', 'END\nREAD', 'GALLONS BILLED\nREAD (PER 1,000)'], ['19XXXXXX', 'Water', '3/4"', '10/02/2021 — 10/26/2021', '25', '1.9', '5.3', '3.4']]
```

Thanks

Comment: This is the result of pasting. Everything looks normal when I paste but I did notice a slight quark in the highlighting order. The last two columns seemed to jump from left-to-right then top-to-bottom where the rest of the table highlights top-to-bottom then left-to-right. However, the texts seems to paste in the right order reguardless. `METER
NUMBER
METER
TYPE
METER
 SIZE
SERVICE
PERIOD
SERVICE
DAYS
BEGIN
READ
END
READ
GALLONS BILLED
(PER 1,000)`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this code but it seems hackish. I'm going to keep trying to tweak the table settings.

```
    table = pdf.extract_table()
    # Clean up extract_table()
    table[0][6] = re.sub(r"END|READ|\n", "", table[0][6]).strip()
    table[0].insert(6, "END READ")
    fixed_values = table[1][6].split(" ")
    del table[1][6]
    table[1] += fixed_values
```